# Does not drag the Qt Designer window

Tags: python, qt-designer

Please tell me why dragging the window does not work. I found a lot of examples on the Internet. I created simple forms without design and tried - everything works there. And for some reason, it is in this version that he does not want to. I couldn't find the logic of these events anywhere.
Or maybe someone can explain the logic of what and how to do in my case.

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def mousePressEvent(self, event):           # <----------
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):            # <----------
            delta = event.globalPos() - self.oldPos
            self.move(self.pos() + delta)
            self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(410, 193)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.Window = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
            self.Window.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 371, 161))
            self.Window.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
    "    border-radius: 7px;\n"
    "    background-color: #ffffff;\n"
    "}")
            self.Window.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
            self.Window.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
            self.Window.setObjectName("Window")
            self.WindowFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Window)
            self.WindowFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 371, 31))
            self.WindowFrame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
    "    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;\n"
    "    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;\n"
    "    background-color: #4375f4;\n"
    "}")
            self.WindowFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
            self.WindowFrame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
            self.WindowFrame.setObjectName("WindowFrame")
            self.CloseWindowButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.WindowFrame)
            self.CloseWindowButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(331, 0, 41, 31))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(11)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.CloseWindowButton.setFont(font)
            self.CloseWindowButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
            self.CloseWindowButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
    "    color: white;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    border-top-right-radius: 7px;\n"
    "    background-color: #4375f4;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover{\n"
    "    background-color: #90aef9;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed{\n"
    "    color: #EA2F4E;\n"
    "}")
            self.CloseWindowButton.setObjectName("CloseWindowButton")
            self.MinimizeWindowButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.WindowFrame)
            self.MinimizeWindowButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 0, 41, 31))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(10)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.MinimizeWindowButton.setFont(font)
            self.MinimizeWindowButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
            self.MinimizeWindowButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
    "    color: white;\n"
    "    border: none;\n"
    "    border-top-right-radius: 7px;\n"
    "    background-color: #4375f4;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover{\n"
    "    background-color: #90aef9;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed{\n"
    "    color: #EA2F4E;\n"
    "}")
            self.MinimizeWindowButton.setDefault(False)
            self.MinimizeWindowButton.setObjectName("MinimizeWindowButton")
            self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.Window)
            self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 301, 31))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(14)
            font.setBold(False)
            font.setWeight(50)
            self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
            self.lineEdit.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
            self.lineEdit.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
            self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {\n"
    " border: 2px solid gray;\n"
    " border-radius: 10px;\n"
    "}")
            self.lineEdit.setInputMask("")
            self.lineEdit.setFrame(True)
            self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
            self.lineEdit.setDragEnabled(False)
            self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(False)
            self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
            self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Window)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 100, 181, 41))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setPointSize(12)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.pushButton.setFont(font)
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
    "    color: white;\n"
    "    border-radius: 8px;\n"
    "    background-color: #4375f4;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:hover{\n"
    "    background-color: #90aef9;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed{\n"
    "    background-color: #7088c1;\n"
    "}")
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(".\\magnifier-1_icon-icons.com_56924 (1).png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.CloseWindowButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
            self.MinimizeWindowButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "_"))
            self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "text"))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "press")) 
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        MainWindow.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the window draggable you should remove the line

```py
MainWindow.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

because it makes the window unresponsive. The *frame* (the titlebar ...) makes the window responsive to dragging.
If you want it to be transparent without a *frame* , you need to implement your own
input system.